# How to query using In operator in Ignite Cache

Tags: ignite, apacheignite

I have an Ignite cache that I am using as table and I want to update multiple rows of that table using a single query.
When I use the In operator it's only working for 1 value and it fails for all others.

From what I understood, In operator does not support var args and only 1 value is accepted.
A lot of solutions point to creating a temp table and using that table for In clause.

So my question is - how to create a temp table if there is a way and how to populate the temp table with list of values at once?

Answer (score 0):

IN operator [does not have the "1 value" limitation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/sql-conformance).

```
SELECT * from mytable where id in (1,2,3)
```

works well. 
Ignite doesn't have a concept of a "temp table".  If you would like to go that route, create a regular table using "[CREATE TABLE](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/sql-reference/ddl#create-table)" command

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot of context, but I *assume* you have a query like this:

```
select * from table where id in (?)
```

And you have one or more values in the query parameter?

If that's it, the trick is to rewrite the query:

```
select t.* from table t join table(id bigint = (?)) i on t.id = i.id
```

Then you pass in your list as an array:

```
var q = new SqlFieldsQuery("...")
           .setArgs((Object[]) new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```